# Getting a differential equation from a given expression

Tags: calculus

This was a question from last year IIT-JEE exam in India:

> If $y^{-\frac14} + y^{\frac14} = 2x$, and $$(x^2-1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + ax\frac{dy}{dx} + by = 0,$$
> Find $|a-b|$.

I tried differentiating the given relation, but the second derivative looked ugly. I suspect one can (brute force) compute the derivatives and plug into the ODE and then read off $a,b$.

**But is there a neat way to solve this problem?**

*My attempt:*
I note that the given relation is invariant under the transformation $y \to \frac1{y}$. So maybe the differential equation must have the same symmetry?
However, if I transform the differential equation, I get terms with $(y')^2$ and I feel like the idea fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this fulfills your aesthetic criteria, but a pretty simple way is to invert the implicit equation for $y$, which yields

$$y=(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^4$$

The first derivative and second derivative is

$$y'=\frac{4y}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
y''=\frac{16y}{x^2-1}-\frac{2xy}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}$$

which yields, after eliminating the remaining square root using the first derivative, the following linear equation:

$$(x^2-1)y''=16 y-\frac{xy'}{2}$$

which exactly of the form given above.

EDIT: The inverse of the above function is actually not unique, since as noted in the question $1/y$ also satisfies the equation above. It turns out however, that both branches satisfy the same differential equation anyway.

Comment: This is a simple, clear and efficient way to solve the problem. (+1)

Comment: It looks neat to me. Thanks.